# DiscreteSeekBar не работает в реализации плеера

Tags: android

Использую библиотеку [DiscreteSeekBar](https://github.com/AnderWeb/discreteSeekBar/blob/master/README.md)  в своем плеере. Цель вопроса скорее всего вместе с опытными разработчиками найти решение проблемы и оставить его другим, кто захочет повторить тоже самое.

Итак, поехали. Мне надо сделать, чтобы помимо показа кружка при удержании `thumb`-а (это поведение самой библиотеки) работала прокрутка трека (с помощью `seekTo`). Также необходимо, чтобы во всплывающем кружке показывалось время в формате HH:mm:ss (или mm:ss, если продолжительность менее часа).

В библиотеке предусмотрена установка слушателя. Наследуем активность от интерфейса `DiscreteSeekBar.OnProgressChangeListener`, далее

```
seekBar.setOnProgressChangeListener(this);
```

И реализуем методы

```
@Override
public void onProgressChanged(DiscreteSeekBar sb, int progress, boolean fromUser)
{

}

@Override
public void onStartTrackingTouch(DiscreteSeekBar sb)
{

}

@Override
public void onStopTrackingTouch(DiscreteSeekBar sb)
{
    player.seekTo(sb.getProgress() * 1000);
}
```

При перетаскивании ползунка проблем нет, но вот если его отпустить, то приложение вылетает, немного подумав. В логах я ничего не могу найти. Пусто. Убрал вызов метода `seekTo`, но это ничего не изменило. Что ж, вскрытие покажет. Сделал Git Clone и добавил исходники себе в проект. Ищем, что происходит в методе `setOnProgressChangeListener(Contexr ctx)`. Там все нормально.

Оказывается `min` и `max`, являются обязательными атрибутами, в тэг xml добавил

```
app:dsb_min="0"
app:dsb_max="100"
```

Ползунок водить можно, но по непонятным причинам, он то нормально перемещается то нет, просто берет и останавливается на половине анимации кружка. То при отпускании не до конца скрывается. Я даже убрал установку слушателя и все равно вылетает.

**SOS!!!**

Я скачал тестовое приложение с Android Arsenal и оно тоже вылетает. Логов нет. В чем проблема может быть?

Lineage 13 (Android 6)

Comment: Может просто перенести вызов метода в `onProgressChanged`?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, дело не в этом :) К тому же мне надо прокручивать именно при отпускании пальца, а не во время его перемещения. Музыка играет по сети

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказывается это [баг либы](https://github.com/AnderWeb/discreteSeekBar/issues/73). Решение - убрать тень

```
app:dsb_indicatorElevation="0dp"
```